# Margin seems not to be working properly

Tags: html, css

Okay, I'll keep it short and simple, what I'm trying to achieve is that I'd like to have a chat on the side of my website as a sidebar, but now I'm trying to add some margin to every side so it closes in, although this doesn't seem to be working properly, here's the code.

**HTML**

```
<div class="inner-chat">
    <div class="chat-box-messages">
        //Messages
    </div>

    <div class="chat-box-input">
        //Field to input
    </div>              
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.inner-chat{
    margin:1vw;
}

.chat-box-messages{
    height:80%;
    background:yellow;
}

.chat-box-input{
    height:20%;
    background:green;
}
```

Then the code produces this,

[image: Image Display]

The most logical thing I would say is that because the margin is pushing on every side that it'll push down, but I would have no idea on how to go about this problem in another way.

Comment: I think the problem is that you are using `%` to define your `div`'s heights. Try using `80%-1vw` instead to make room for your margin.

Comment: @Lae Thank you! Learned something new! Since I can't accept this as an answer I'll go ahead and accept Terry 's which basically says the same, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sum of the heights of `div.chat-box-messages` and `div.chat-box-input` amounts to precisely 100%. And your `1vw` vertical margins adds **on top** of that calculated height, causing the child elements to overflow the parent. In order to account for the additional margin, you have to subtract a total of `2vw` from the final height. One way is to use `calc(80% - 1vw)` and `calc(20% - 1vw)` for the heights of the child elements, i.e.:

```
.chat-box-messages{
    height: calc(80% - 1vw);
    background:yellow;
}

.chat-box-input{
    height: calc(20% - 1vw);
    background:green;
}
```

You can of course perform any other kind of permutations on the height, such as using `calc(80% - 2vw)` and sticking to 20% height of the other element.

Comment: Yeap, thank you! I never actually knew I had to make room for my margin. This works perfectly!